# php, mysql and phpmyadmin, MAMP or homebrew

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp, homebrew

When I got to make a clean install of my system I asked myself, again, this question.
What is the best way tools to use for my local development, install MAMP or install the stack with homebrew?

Even though 'best' is highly relative depending on what each and everybody needs and how they like to work, I would like to get some thoughts from people who tried them both, what they finally chose and why.

Personally, I chose this time to not use MAMP and install php, mysql and (not yet) phpmyadmin using homebrew.
The pros, it's simple and fast to install, even better to update. Painfull to update MAMP.
The cons, having the homebrew.mxcl.mysql daemon running and having to manually start-stop processes like apache and mysql while there is just a button on MAMP.

But still, how about installing and using both?
Would I enjoy the best of both worlds or am I looking for troubles and headaches?

Thanks y'all...

Comment: Just stick with homebrew and start coding.  Don't use both.  There is no way to get an objective, constructive answer with your question.

Comment: well you gave me the answer, don't use both and it is objective.  now for the constructive part, some answers like Kursion's is what I was expecting, just some opinions and advices. but thanks danronmoon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did this a hundred of times... !

- Using MAMP or WAMP is fair enough for beginners but you'll stick to their configuration(s) and tricks which make you a bit dependent of their products. This is only my opinion but I would prefer to install a homebrew configuration.
- When installing services such as MySQL, PHPMyAdmin, Apache+PHP or NGINX+PHP/PHP-FPM you will learn much more things. You'll be independant as you go through the installation and read the documentations. You can also simplify the work for futher installation by:

  1) Creating some general pre-set configuration files

  2) Creating your own installation script(s)

And voila !

Comment: Higher learning and eventually more flexibility was indeed my main goal with opting for a homebrew configuration.    Do you also install PHPMyAdmin with homebrew or with the official installer from their website ?  Again, an update can be a bit late with homebrew but I really appreciate the simplicity to install it when available...

Comment: For PHPMyAdmin you only need to copy the folder into your www folder. After that you can edit the configuration either in the config.inc.php file or from the setup.php script that is avaliable for you.

PS: don't forget to upvote or downvote ;)